# Using Fourier Series to model a vibrating string

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am really struggling with the problem:

> Consider a vibrating string occupying the interval $0\leq x \leq l$. Suppose the string is strucked in the middle so that its initial displacement is zero but its initial velocity $u_{t}(x,t)$ is $1$ for $|x-\frac{1}{2}l|<\delta$ and $0$ elsewhere. Find $u(x,t)$ for $t>0$.

I am having the most trouble with the fact that the velocity is only $1$ on $(\frac{1}{2}l-\delta, \frac{1}{2}l+\delta)$. I don't know how to find a Fourier series that satisfies this condition. If I ignore this and assume that the velocity is $1$ on $[0,l]$, then I get something like

$$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4l}{(2n-1)^{2}\pi^{2}c} \sin \frac{(2n-1)\pi x}{l} \sin \frac{(2n-1) \pi ct}{l}$$

The **correct answer** should be
$$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4l (-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)^{2}\pi^{2}c} \sin \frac{(2n-1) \pi \delta}{l} \sin \frac{(2n-1)\pi x}{l} \sin \frac{(2n-1) \pi ct}{l}$$

I am thinking that, because I assumed the velocity was $1$ on the whole interval $[0,l]$, so if I multiply the expression by the Fourier series for $\begin{cases}1 & |x-\frac{1}{2}l|<\delta \\ 0 & |x-\frac{1}{2}l|\geq\delta\end{cases}$, then I should get the correct answer? And comparing the correct answer to what I got, it seems like that Fourier series would be $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \sin \frac{(2n-1)\pi \delta}{l}$. I have no clue how to find this series.

Any help is appreciated!

p.s. We have learned that for a vibrating string, the conditions are
$$ u_{tt} = c^{2} u_{xx}, \quad u(x,0) = f(x), \quad u_{t}(x,0) = g(x), \quad u(0,t) = u(l,t) = 0. $$

where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are defined on $[0,l]$ and their Fourier series are
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n} \sin \frac{n \pi x}{l}, \quad g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n} \sin \frac{n \pi x}{l}$$

And the general solution is
$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin \frac{n\pi x}{l} \left(b_{n} \cos \frac{n \pi c t}{l} + \frac{lB_{n}}{n\pi c} \sin \frac{n \pi c t}{l} \right) $$

In this problem, since the initial displacement is $0$, I took $f (x)$ to be $0$. Then I think $u(x,t)$ will be in the form
$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin \frac{n\pi x}{l} \left(\frac{lB_{n}}{n\pi c} \sin \frac{n \pi c t}{l} \right) $$

Comment: Since you are using the $\sin$ half series, you need to compute the Fourier series of $g$  in a similar manner. Since the initial displacement is zero the $b_n$ are zero. You need to compute the $B_n$.

Comment: @copper.hat I computed $B_n$ assuming that $g(x)=1$ on $[0,l]$ (please see the answer I got). I really don't know how to compute $B_{n}$ so that $g(x)$ is only $1$ on $(1/2l - \delta, 1/2l + \delta)$. If I do $B_{n}= \frac{2}{l} \int_{1/2l-\delta}^{1/2l+\delta} \sin \frac{n\pi x}{l} dx$, then there will be $\delta$ in the $\cos$ function I cannot get rid of.

Comment: @J.G. That was a misprint in the problem. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I get $B_n = {2 \over \pi n} \sin ( {\pi n \over 2} ) \sin ( {\pi n \over l} \delta)$. You need to use the difference of $\cos$ formula to get rid of the $\cos$. Then take the $\sin ( {\pi n \over 2} )$ into account.

Comment: @copper.hat Oh my goodness. That's it! Thank you. Also I think the numerator should be $4$ instead of $2$.

Comment: Glad to help you iron out your issue.